# Error in deployment when updated from angular 4 to 5 on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, azure, asp.net-core

I, am using angular template from visual studio asp.net core 2.0. Then I, have updated angular 4 to angular 5 http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/. On local machine everything is working fine . I am using visual studio publish method to deployed to Azure. The application deployed successfully. But when browse the page getting an error as

**Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.**

On visual studio project web.config file is not present. However, on published file I can see the web.config file in Azure location.So I edited an added below code in web.config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
<environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
      </environmentVariables>s
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 0271f403-40b1-4744-b526-d843041f247f-->
```

This solve me the above error. But created a new error as below
[image: found error]

The logs files are not created as per the web.config file code

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

Find some solution from other link as edit the startup.cs file then add

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
```

Replace all occurrences of AotPlugin with AngularCompilerPlugin and added

```
const zone: NgZone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);
```

in webpack.config.js.

The deployment is not working for me . Can anyone please let me know how can I resolve this issue. I, am trying to resolve this issue from past 1 day. I have updated to angular 5 the angular template from visual deployment was working fine.

Comment: You can find the steps to troubleshoot this error [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-iis-errors-reference) about mid-page. You likely need to install the [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle).

Comment: by changing env_variable to development you can get to know the exact error. so that we can try to guide you.

Comment: `Development environment should` that's not an error but warning.
You should read actual error instead in response,
see here - https://www.recaffeinate.co/post/serialize-errors-as-json-in-aspnetcore/

Answer (score 0):

After updating from Angular 4 to 5 I face similar problems while deploying. But based on my issues it leads me to change few things.

**1.** Comment out **HMR** in startup.cs

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment()){
      // app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
     //  {
     //    HotModuleReplacement = true
     //  });
    }
```

**2.** Disable **SSR** in Index.cshtml.

`<app>loading..<app>`

**Note**: due to these issues official Team came up with new template for angular 5.